# Create Texture on canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, colors

I want to create a texture on a canvas. You can choose between 2 and 5 colours. For each colour you can specify the percentage. The distribution of the colours on the canvas should be even.

I hold the possible colors in an array and randomly select the index and thus assign the color. If i choose a big mixing ratio (i.e. 60% and 40%) it seems to work. But if the ratio gets smaller(i.e. 90%/10%), the result is not ok.
The problem is that towards the end of the line only the color with 90% appears.
For pixelmanipulation i use ImageData. My idea was to manipulate "row by row".

Please bear with me, I am JS beginner and do not speak English native
This is my Code:

```
  generateTexture(colors) {
  if (colors.length > 0) {
    let myColors = colors.slice();
    let canvas = document.getElementById('mycanvas');
    const w = canvas.getBoundingClientRect().width * 4;
    const h = canvas.getBoundingClientRect().height * 4;
    let context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    let i = 0;
    let sum = w * h;
    for (i = 0; i < myColors.length; i++) {
      myColors[i].sum = (sum / 100) * myColors[i].percentage;
      myColors[i].rowsum = myColors[i].sum / h;
    }

    let imageData = context.getImageData(0, 0, w, h);
    let data = imageData.data;
    let height = 0;
    while (height <= h) {
      for (i = 0; i < myColors.length; i++) {
        myColors[i].sum = myColors[i].rowsum;
      }
      let start = 0;
      start = height * h;
      let end = start + w * 4;
      let x = start;
      while (x < end) {
        let colIndex = 0;
        if (colors.length > 1) {
          colIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * myColors.length);
        }
        if (myColors[colIndex].sum > 0) {
          let val = myColors[colIndex].color.split(',');
          let r = parseInt(val[0]);
          let g = parseInt(val[1]);
          let b = parseInt(val[2]);
          data[x] = r;
          data[x + 1] = g;
          data[x + 2] = b;
          data[x + 3] = 255;
          myColors[colIndex].sum = myColors[colIndex].sum - 1;
          x = x + 4;
        }
      }
      height++;
    }
    context.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
    canvas.style.webkitFilter = 'blur(.35px)';
  }
},
```

},

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems with your function.

### Canvas resolution

`canvas.getBoundingClientRect().width` may or may not return the canvas resolution. What it returns is the size on the page. Use `canvas.width` and `canvas.height` to get the resolution of the canvas.

### Wrong height value

You multiply height by 4. Thus the total number of pixels channels (RGBA) you are filling is `w * 4 * h * 4` which 4 times too many. It should be `w * h * 4`

### Randomness

The function `generateTexture` is not truly random as you are randomly picking from a small number of colors which does not represent the true distribution you are after with the percentages.

Say you have 90% blue and 10% red.

When you pick a color you randomly pick blue or red, 50/50 even odds, so for the first 20% of the image it will be 50% blue and 50% red. Then you run out of red (used up the 10%) and you have nothing to pick from but blue.

The result is bands of random distribution till the last which is just one color.

#### Example of poor distribution

Example of how your selection results in a very non random texture. (Banding)

```js
function generateTexture(colors, ctx) {
    var i;
    const colSel = [...colors];
    const imgData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
    const data32 = new Uint32Array(imgData.data.buffer);
    const pixels = data32.length;
    for (const col of colSel) {
        const rgb = col.color.split(',');
        col.RGBA32 = 0xFF000000 + ((rgb[2] & 0xFF) << 16) + ((rgb[1] & 0xFF) << 8) + (rgb[0] & 0xFF);
        col.pixels = Math.round(pixels * (col.percentage / 100));
    }
    i = 0;
    while (i < pixels) { 
        const idx = Math.random() * colSel.length | 0;
        const col = colSel[idx];
        data32[i++] = col.RGBA32;
        col.pixels --;
        if (col.pixels <= 0) {
            colSel.splice(idx, 1);
            if (colSel.length === 1) {
                const col = colSel[0];
                while (i < pixels) { data32[i++] = col.RGBA32 }
            }
        }
    }
    ctx.putImageData(imgData, 0, 0);

}




const colors = [];
const sum = 100;
var colCount = 0;
canvas.addEventListener("click", randomize);
function randomize(){
    colors.length = colCount = 0;
    colList.innerHTML = "";
    while(colCount < 100) {
        const col = randomColor();
        colors.push(col);
        $$(colList, $$($("li"),
            $("span", {textContent: col.percentage + "%"}),
            $("span", { className: "colBox", style: "background:rgb("+col.color+ ");"})
        ));
    }
    generateTexture(colors, canvas.getContext("2d"));
}
const randByte = () => Math.random() * 255 | 0;
function randomColor() {
    const remaining = sum - colCount;
    const percentage = remaining < 5 ? remaining  : (Math.random()** 0.33)* remaining | 0;
    colCount += percentage;
    return {
        color: [randByte(), randByte(), randByte()].join(","),
        percentage,
    }
}
const $$ = (el, ...sibs) => sibs.reduce((e,sib)=>(e.appendChild(sib), e), el);
const $ = (tag, p ={}) => Object.assign(document.createElement(tag),p);
randomize();
```

```css
* {margin: 0px; font-family: arial}
canvas {
  position: absolute;
  top: opx;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  image-rendering: pixelated;
}
div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  background: white;
  padding: 2px 4px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
#colList {

}
.colBox {
   width: 64px;
   height: 1.2em;
   position: absolute;
   right: 4px;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"  width="75" height="30"></canvas>
<div>Click for another example run
<ul id="colList"> </ul>
</div>
```

### Random items by percentage

You say this is a texture so, does it really matter if the number of actual pixel match the needed percentage.

If you create an array with 100 colors in it. For the 90% color add it to the array 90 times, for the 10% add it 10 times.

Then randomly pick from that array and you will get the distribution you want.

#### Example true random distribution

```js
function generateTexture(colors, ctx) {
    var len, i, colSel = [];

      for (const col of colors) {
          const rgb = col.color.split(',');
          const RGBA32 = 0xFF000000 + ((rgb[2] & 0xFF) << 16) + ((rgb[1] & 0xFF) << 8) + (rgb[0] & 0xFF);
          i = col.percentage;

          while (i-- > 0) { colSel.push(RGBA32) }
      }

      const imgData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
      const data32 = new Uint32Array(imgData.data.buffer);
      i = len = data32.length;
      while (i-- > 0) { data32[i] =  colSel[Math.random() * 100 | 0] }
      ctx.putImageData(imgData, 0, 0);

}




const colors = [];
const sum = 100;
var colCount = 0;
canvas.addEventListener("click", randomize);
function randomize(){
    colors.length = colCount = 0;
    colList.innerHTML = "";
    while(colCount < 100) {
        const col = randomColor();
        colors.push(col);
        $$(colList, $$($("li"),
            $("span", {textContent: col.percentage + "%"}),
            $("span", { className: "colBox", style: "background:rgb("+col.color+ ");"})
        ));
    }
    generateTexture(colors, canvas.getContext("2d"));
}
const randByte = () => Math.random() * 255 | 0;
function randomColor() {
    const remaining = sum - colCount;
    const percentage = remaining < 5 ? remaining : (Math.random()** 0.33)* remaining | 0;
    colCount += percentage;
    return {
        color: [randByte(), randByte(), randByte()].join(","),
        percentage,
    }
}
const $$ = (el, ...sibs) => sibs.reduce((e,sib)=>(e.appendChild(sib), e), el);
const $ = (tag, p ={}) => Object.assign(document.createElement(tag),p);
randomize();
```

```css
* {margin: 0px; font-family: arial}
canvas {
  position: absolute;
  top: opx;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  image-rendering: pixelated;
}
div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  background: white;
  padding: 2px 4px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
#colList {

}
.colBox {
   width: 64px;
   height: 1.2em;
   position: absolute;
   right: 4px;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"  width="75" height="30"></canvas>
<div>Click for random texture
<ul id="colList"> </ul>
</div>
```

### Shuffle pixels

If it is very important that the correct number of pixels for each color is in the image then you can use a random shuffle.

Add the colors 1 by 1 to the image to the exact counts needed.

Then randomly shuffle the pixels.

#### Example Random shuffle

```js
function generateTexture(colors, ctx) {
    var i, idx = 0, RGBA32;
    const imgData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
    const data32 = new Uint32Array(imgData.data.buffer);
    const pixels = data32.length;
    for (const col of colors) {
        const rgb = col.color.split(',');
        RGBA32 = 0xFF000000 + ((rgb[2] & 0xFF) << 16) + ((rgb[1] & 0xFF) << 8) + (rgb[0] & 0xFF);
        
        i = Math.round((col.percentage / 100) * pixels);
        while(i-- >= 0) { data32[idx++] = RGBA32 }
    }
    // fill any remaining pixels with last color
    while(idx < pixels) { data32[idx++] = RGBA32 };


    // shuffle pixels
    i = 0;
    while (i < pixels) { 
        const rIdx = Math.random() * (pixels-i) + i  | 0;
        const p = data32[i];
        data32[i++] = data32[rIdx]
        data32[rIdx] = p;
    }
    ctx.putImageData(imgData, 0, 0);

}




const colors = [];
const sum = 100;
var colCount = 0;
canvas.addEventListener("click", randomize);
function randomize(){
    colors.length = colCount = 0;
    colList.innerHTML = "";
    while(colCount < 100) {
        const col = randomColor();
        colors.push(col);
        $$(colList, $$($("li"),
            $("span", {textContent: col.percentage + "%"}),
            $("span", { className: "colBox", style: "background:rgb("+col.color+ ");"})
        ));
    }
    generateTexture(colors, canvas.getContext("2d"));
}
const randByte = () => Math.random() * 255 | 0;
function randomColor() {
    const remaining = sum - colCount;
    const percentage = remaining < 5 ? remaining : (Math.random()** 0.33)* remaining | 0;
    colCount += percentage;
    return {
        color: [randByte(), randByte(), randByte()].join(","),
        percentage,
    }
}
const $$ = (el, ...sibs) => sibs.reduce((e,sib)=>(e.appendChild(sib), e), el);
const $ = (tag, p ={}) => Object.assign(document.createElement(tag),p);
randomize();
```

```css
* {margin: 0px; font-family: arial}
canvas {
  position: absolute;
  top: opx;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  image-rendering: pixelated;
}
div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  background: white;
  padding: 2px 4px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
#colList {

}
.colBox {
   width: 64px;
   height: 1.2em;
   position: absolute;
   right: 4px;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="75" height="30"></canvas>
<div>Click for random texture
<ul id="colList"> </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! Your answer saved my day :-)